# Question about Geometry involving angles and lines

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

The answer is C however if angle ACD is 110 degrees and angle AB is 110 degrees how does it equal 180?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's an isosceles triangle, angles $B, C$ (the angles opposite segments $AC, AB$  respectively, which are equal in length) are *equal in measure*: 
$$ \angle B = \angle C$$

We also know the the sum of the measures of the angles of a triangle sum to $180^\circ$.

$$\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = \angle A + 2 \angle C = 180^\circ $$ $$\implies 40^\circ + 2 \angle C = 180^\circ \implies 2\angle C = 180^\circ - 40^\circ = 140^\circ$$

Solve for (the measure of) angle $C$: $$\angle B = \angle C = \dfrac{140^\circ}{2} = 70^\circ$$

Since $\angle C$ and $\angle ACD$ (the unknown angle) are *supplementary angles* (since $B, C, D$ are colinear: they lie on the same straight line), we know that the sum of the measures of $\angle C$ and $\angle ACD$ is $180^\circ$

$$\angle C + \angle ACD = 180^\circ\implies \angle ACD = 180^\circ - \angle C = 180^\circ - 70^\circ = 110^\circ$$

The answer is, indeed, that the measure of $$\angle ACD = 110^\circ$$

Comment: Where does the 2 come from?

Comment: Because the $\angle C = \angle B$, so $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = \angle A + \angle C +\angle C = \angle A + 2\angle C = 180^\circ$  $\angle A + 2 \angle C = 180 \implies 40 + 2\angle C = 180 \implies 2\angle C = 180 - 40 = 140$

Comment: $\angle B = \angle C = 70^\circ$, and we have that the sum of angle A + angle B = $40 + 70 = 110 = \angle ACD$

Comment: the measure of an exterior angle is equal to the sum of the measures of interior angles opposing it.

Comment: Is this clear now, Jon?

Comment: I understand why the answer is 110 because the exterior angle is outside 110 and the interior is 70 degrees inside the sum of 70 + 110 is 180. Thus the answer.

Comment: Great: you got it!

Answer (score 1):

The internal angles of a triangle add up to $180^{\circ}$.

Since $\angle BAC = 40^{\circ}$ it follows that $\angle ABC + \angle ACB = 140^{\circ}$. Moreover, since $AB=AC$ it follows, by symmetry, that $\angle ABC = \angle ACB$. Hence: $\angle ABC = \angle ACB = 70^{\circ}$.

Since $B$, $C$ and $D$ are colinear, it follows that $\angle ACB + \angle ACD = 180^{\circ}$. We know that $\angle ACB = 70^{\circ}$ and hence $\angle ACD = 110^{\circ}$.